# Fetching JIRA profile image

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

So I've created a website where the user needs to log in (same login as to Jira), and I now want to make a profile page with their image from Jira. Is there a way to get the user's Jira Profile picture and display it on a PHP page? I did try to use `Python` and `PHP` from this example: [Jira Example](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-avatars/#api-rest-api-3-universal-avatar-type-type-owner-entityid-get) But can't make it work.

Does anyone know if there is a way for me to fetch the user's profile image?

Answer (score 1):

The example you linked to is for Project/system avatars, such as project avatars and issuetype icons.

The [Get User](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-users/#api-rest-api-3-user-get) endpoint will provide what you need. In the return value will be a property avatarUrls which contains urls to different sizes of the user's profile image